# Can adding more energy cause the temperature to drop again?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, statistical-mechanics, temperature

In a system, the total energy is composed of *Electronic >> Vibrational > Rotational >> Translational*.

As far as I understand, temperature is only related to the average kinetic energy, which includes Vibrational, Rotational, and Translational components and not electronic energy (excitement states)??

If theoretically, so much energy is added to the system that initially, the temperature increases due to these first three degrees of freedom, but then more and more electronic excited states are populated because the molecules kinetic energy provides enough that electronic excitation occurs, which, of course, takes up that kinetic energy, wouldn't this lead to brief drops in temperature with energy input?

Answer (score 2):

For an ideal gas, no, because the new modes of "energy storage" are not instantaneously added to all molecules at the same time. Here's a rough sketch (from wikipedia) of how the specific heat changes as with temperature:

[image]

During phase changes, however, you do add energy to a system without raising the temperature. The temperature does not go down.